# Which is a better Unix Distribution to learn from a job perspective

Tags: linux, unix

I work on text mining and statistical modeling, mostly course and research projects at school. I have primarily been using the Windows GUI versions of R and Python. I will be done soon and I realize that going into the industry, most work is done on Unix/Linux machines.

I wanted to get some hands on experience working on Unix before I start looking for jobs (in about 6 months), especially at the command line. I wanted to ask you guys for two things -

a. Which unix/linux distribution would be most beneficial in getting familiar with. I understand that most of the knowledge will scale across distributions, but I still wanted to know which one would be the best to invest time on.

b. Is there any resource or book to help me pick up speed on working from the command line instead of a GUI as in Gnome or KDE.

I am not sure if it matters, but I also wanted to mention that alongside I also want to invest some time in learning the basics of Hadoop, Pig and Mahout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Ubuntu myself, but for your purposes, it doesn't matter too much which one you choose - as long as the chosen one doesn't eat up all your time learning UNIX itself - you want to focus on tools, not on system administration.

**Better to spend time learning an editor (vim/emacs), a scripting language (Python, Ruby), and mapreduce (Hadoop, Pig, and Mahout).**

Comment: I actually was reading some material and was slightly overwhelmed with all the stuff about editors and scripts and all. This makes it nice and clear. One needs an editor to write the scripts, the algorithms to go into the scripts and the inbuilt functionality of the relevant scripting language.

Comment: The shortest path to Hadoop (your true target for text mining and statistical modeling) is probably vim, Python, Hadoop.  You could use some other text editor just to get going, but for the best long-run productivity, it helps to learn vim.  When you have a chance, also learn R for statistics.

Comment: Just learn vim in the beginning. It is very powerful and you only need to know the basics. You can get into Emacs later, but it has a much steeper learning curve. I was a hardcore Emacs user for a while. Then I switched to Eclipse, and now vim is my default non-GUI text editor.

Comment: @ObscureRobot - +1 sounds eerily like my experience.  I started using vi/vim, but workers at my second job converted me to xemacs (aka **the kitchen sink** - even its icon was a **kitchen sink**) , but after suffering from emacs-pinky (LEFT-CNTRL), I went back to vim and haven't gone back.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't worry much about the specific Linux distribution you end up learning. It almost certainly won't be the same as what they use at your eventual employer. Instead, pick a distribution that your friends and fellow students use. If no one else is using Linux, then [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) is a good place to start.

You should also consider learning Mac OS X. The differences aren't huge, but more and more developers prefer to use OS X as their desktop unix environment.

You should also take some time to learn the basics of SQL. At the very least, grab [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) so that you can make a database and run some queries. If you want to go deeper, give [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) a try. Big statistical analysis projects often have SQL databases to manage the data sets. Even with medium sized projects, you may find it much easier to work with your data in a database than in flat files.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with others Ubuntu is great for you to learn. Many companies opt for Red Hat Enterprise Linux because they can get official support, and companies like support.
CentOS is a free equivalent to that.

I like [Unix Power Tools](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/index.htm) as a resource for the command line, and you can always google for "unix shell tips" and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the Unix Power Tools reference.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most user friendly Linux distributions nowadays is without any doubt Ubuntu. There are ton's of guide on the Linux shell out there on the web.

However it is a question for Super user ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are [Hadoop VMs](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera%27s+Hadoop+Demo+VM) from Cloudera. You can use them on Linux or Windows. In general, VMs are good idea to learn almost anything, because you don't have to worry about trashing your main system, just because you followed some random bloggers instructions.You can use multiple VMs to simulate a small Hadoop cluster.